# Unable to upgrade Kali to Debian

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, kali-linux

Tried to upgrade kali to debian and got an error upgrading dash 0.5.8-2.5 to 0.5.8-2.6. As the result sh not found. Restored system by:

```
rm /bin/sh        
ln -s /usr/bin/dash /bin/sh
```

Cuz /bin/sh gets wrong symlink when I try to reinstall dash 
Tried to reinstall dash and got the same error:

```
apt install dash --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/113 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 426445 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dash_0.5.8-2.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking dash (0.5.8-2.6) over (0.5.8-2.6) ...
Setting up dash (0.5.8-2.6) ...
Removing 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /bin/sh to /bin/sh.distrib by dash'
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by bash'
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/man/man1/sh.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/sh.distrib.1.gz by dash'
dpkg: error: error executing hook 'if { test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = add-architecture || test "$DPKG_HOOK_ACTION" = remove-architecture; } && test -x /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook; then /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook update; fi', exit code 32512
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release:    9.0
Codename:   stretch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no supported upgrade path from Kali to Debian. If you want to use Debian instead of Kali, you need to install Debian, using the Debian installer (download an [installer image](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst)), over your Kali setup. You’ll have to back up any data you want to keep beforehand.

In this particular case you’re running into [a bug in `dash`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=888227); this also indicates you’re trying to install Debian unstable which isn’t recommended if you’re not *very* familiar with the system. You should install Debian stable instead.

Comment: everything was upgraded ok, dash was fixed so now it's ok